# How to replay a currently displayed drawable animation in an Imageview

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have created a single Imageview which displays a drawable animation, depending if the user clicks the button 1(first animation will display in Imageview), then button 2 (second animation will display in ImageView). My main problem is the repeat button, since I want it to work in a way wherein if a user clicks this repeat button, the currently displayed/selected animation in the ImageView will display/animate again (Whether user clicked the button 1 or button 2). Kindly take a look at my repeat button code, when I debugged it, my app will crash when this class is called. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

This is my working code without the repeat button:

public class AnimatedImage extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animatedimage);


    //Button1
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1animation);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView displayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);
            displayimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_1);
            displayimage.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) displayimage.getBackground
                            ();
                    frameAnimation.stop();
                    frameAnimation.start();

                }
            });
        }
    });

    //Button 2

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2animation);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView displayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);
            displayimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_2);
            displayimage.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) displayimage.getBackground
                            ();
                    frameAnimation2.stop();
                    frameAnimation2.start();

                }
            });


        }
    });
}}
```

And this is the part that makes my app crash:

```
  //SignRepeat
    Button repeatBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.repeatbtn);
    repeatBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView repImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);

            if (repImage.equals(R.drawable.animation_1)) {
                repImage.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.animation_1));
                repImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation3 = (AnimationDrawable) repImage.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation3.stop();
                        frameAnimation3.start(); }});
            }else {

                repImage.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.animation_2));
                repImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) repImage.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation4.stop();
                        frameAnimation4.start(); }});
            }
        }
            });
```

UPDATE:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ImageView repImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);

            if (repImage.getTag().equals(R.drawable.animation_a)) {
                repImage.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.animation_a));
                repImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation3 = (AnimationDrawable) repImage.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation3.stop();
                        frameAnimation3.start(); }});
            }else if (repImage.getTag().equals(R.drawable.animation_b)){

                repImage.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.animation_b));
                repImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation4 = (AnimationDrawable) repImage.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation4.stop();
                        frameAnimation4.start(); }});
            }

            else {
                repImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose between button1  and button2",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error in the logcat?

Comment: First line says: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last bit:

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) repImage.getBackground();
frameAnimation4.stop();
frameAnimation4.start();
```

You define frameAnimation here, but start frameAnimation4. Try renaming things to match.

Update:

Where you define your imageviews, add in 2 lines after to set a tag on the btn1 click:

```
final ImageView displayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);
int tag= R.drawable.drawable_animation1;
displayimage.setTag(tag);
```

And again for btn2 click:

```
final ImageView displayimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewsign1);
int tag= R.drawable.drawable_animation2;
displayimage.setTag(tag);
```

And finally for your compare line:

```
 if (repImage.getTag().equals(R.drawable.drawable_animation1)) {
```

Comment: Good eye there, I've renamed it , but it still crashes?

Comment: Is there a new error in the logcat? I made a small app out using your code and there is no issue when I run it.

Comment: I still get the same error in logcat: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java:94) May I see where you append the repeat button?

Comment: Hi Whitney, I tried to remake the .class and it no longer crashes, but when I click the repeat button, it only satisfies my else condition and it only calls the animation2, it can't replay animation1 when I click the button1. I'm not sure it may be ignoring my first condition

Comment: This line: repImage.equals(R.drawable.animation_1); it is comparing an imageview to an integer. I researched and it looks like you can't get the resource id from an image view. You can however set a tag and then get that tag later. See the update in my answer above. It worked in my test code.

Comment: It finally worked Whitney, thank you so much for sharing some spare time to help me with this code. I have one last problem though, as I have noticed that when I initially click either button 1 or button 2, and then the repeat button, it's working fine. But when I click the repeat button first without choosing between button1 and button2, it crashes again (XYZ stopped working). I had my code updated on the latter part where I attempted to use toast and another static drawable by changing it to nested if-else. I would really appreciate further assistance with this.

Comment: Good, glad you were able to solve the issue! (sorry was out until today)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a way to solve it, I called the replay button id to my button1 and button2 by using setEnabled, but before that I unchecked the enabled property of the button.These are the lines I've added.

```
 Button replay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_reply);
 replay.setEnabled(true);
```

Alternatively you can also play with the visibility property.
Hope this helps in case anyone got in the same scenario. :)